# Replace quote mark character in table using SQL

Tags: sql-server, replace, find

I am trying to do a simple find and replace query using MSSQL, however the query runs without removing the character.Keep in mine I want a query without having to list the unique data in each row.

## Current row

```
    Number 
    ''12454545''
    ''12454''
    ''1895622''
    ''9846252''
```

## Required Output

```
    Number 
    12454545
    12454
    1895622
    9846252
```

Therefore I only need to remove the ('') from the value in each row. The find and replace function in Excel is exactly the principle required here.

Here are two of the queries I have tried that runs successfully, however it does not remove the ('') .

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET [Number] = REPLACE([Number], '''', '')

SELECT REPLACE([Number], '''', '') FROM [Table]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your query `SELECT REPLACE([Number], '''', '') FROM [Table]` gives column value as expected then your updated query must work

Comment: Def gives me a column value but not replacing the quotations by removing it.

Comment: Are you sure it's a plain single quote? What's the result of `SELECT ASCII([Number]) FROM [Table]`? Is it really character 39?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET [Number] = REPLACE([Number], '"', '')
```

This basically have the same impact as replacing two '', because each individual ' will be replaced.

I'm not sure why exactly its not working but I can guess its because how SQL-SERVER deals with quotes in a string and '''' is the same as '', so when you put an individual quote mark it will be recognized.

Comment: Hi. Tried it, but I believe due to the fact that the '' is now an uneven number, it sees it still as an open command that requires another (') to close the query. Is that making any sense though?

Comment: I don't understand, what happens when you run my query? @ChantelleBrink

Comment: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '', ')

Comment: Thanks, also not  sure how to go around it. Will keep trying though.

Comment: What output do you get from the select you posted? @ChantelleBrink

Comment: It also runs successfully, and then obviously only outputs the specific column in the table, but also not removing the quotations.

Comment: Are you sure its double ' - '' and not " ?

Comment: Yip it just a normal '' quotation or a double apostrophe. Really not sure what I am missing or where I am going wrong.

Comment: Great @chantellebrink

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think you can use `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` before your query something like this -

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

UPDATE [Table]
SET [Number] = REPLACE([Number], "'", "")

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

Comment: Def see where you are going with this, does however run successfully but still not removing the quotations. Not sure what I am doing wrong here or missing.

Answer (score 2):

Your reply to my comment suggests that you're dealing with ASCII character 34, which is a plain double quote ("), not the single quote (' character 39) that you're trying to replace with your current code.

Instead try:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Number] = REPLACE([Number], '"', '')
```

Or, to make it more obvious:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Number] = REPLACE([Number], CHAR(34), '')
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Sorry for the confusion here with regards to the single and double etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET [Number] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Number],'''',''),'"','')
```

Comment: Hi Ajmot - Also not woking. Getting the following error. An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.